# Passing a property by ref

Tags: c#, properties, instance, ref

i have the following classes:

```
    public class Red
    {
        public List<Blue> theList = new List<Blue>();
    }
    public class Blue
    {
        private Red origin;

        public Blue(ref Red)
        {
            origin = Red;
        }

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            origin.theList.Add(new Blue(ref origin));//When calling this, i get the error
        }
    }
```

now it tells me that i cant pass origin as a ref(for whatever reason)
but i need every Blue instance to have a ref to Red. so that i can have a live version of it, and that every Blue instance will access the current version of Red(not a copy)

so i need the following to work:

```
    using System;
    public static class Program
    {
        public static Main(string[] Args)
        {
            Red red = new Red();
            red.Add(new Blue(ref red));
            red.Add(new Blue(ref red));
            red.[0].SomeMethod();
            Console.WriteLine(red[0].origin.Count()); //Should be 2, because red was edited after the first blue instance was created
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your terminology is not correct. Your `origin` is a _field_ (class-level variable), not a _property_. What is the exact error message from the compiler (EDIT or is it a runtime exception?)?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass by reference since you don't need to modify `red`'s location.

```
public class Red
{
    public List<Blue> theList = new List<Blue>();
}

public class Blue
{
    private Red origin;

    public Blue(Red red)
    {
        origin = red;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        origin.theList.Add(new Blue(origin));
    }
}
```

Since `Red` and `Blue` are [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx) their location is passed instead of their value.

Comment: Ok thanks, i thought when setting a property, it would be a copy of that instance, and not the instance(by reference) itself, i needed this because im making something where objects need to keep track of their parent objects, and i dont want it to create massive amounts of duplicates of a few objects

Comment: It is a copy to the location of the instance (passing the reference). The `ref` keyword is used when you need to modify the location of the instance (very rarely).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ref` on instances. It is reference of the same object. You need ref and out for things like integers, strings. Pass everything just as it is without ref.